# xeon E5-2600 ram overclock

Tags: memory, xeon

I got an application whose bottleneck is memory bandwidth.

Did some bench with i7 3820. It's much faster with 2400MHz than 1600MHz RAM.

Could Xeon E5-2670 handle faster ram than 1600MHz (non ECC) ?

Answer (score 0):

That Xeon model works with 1600mhz memories, but you can overclock it to get better results and reduce the bottleneck.